# CLANG is ignoring AVX2 intrinsics in this code

Tags: clang, llvm, intrinsics, avx, avx2

I'm testing LLVM's ability to vectorize some code in https://rust.godbolt.org/
Options : -mavx2 -ffast-math -fno-math-errno -O3
Compiler LLVM 13, but any LLVM actually does the same thing.

```
#include <immintrin.h> 

template<class T>
    struct V4
    {
        T A,B,C,D;

        V4() { };
        V4(T x) : A(x), B(x), C(x), D(x) { };
        V4(T a, T b, T c, T d) : A(a), B(b), C(c), D(d) { };

        void operator +=(const V4& x)
        {
            //A += x.A; B += x.B; C += x.C; D += x.D;
            __m256 f = _mm256_loadu_ps(&A);
            __m256 f2 = _mm256_loadu_ps(&x.A);
            _mm256_store_ps(&A, _mm256_add_ps(f, f2));
        };
        T GetSum() const { return A + B + C + D; };
    };
typedef V4<float> V4F;


double FN(float f[4], float g[4], int cnt) 
{
    V4F vec1(f[0], f[1], f[2], f[3]), vec2(g[0], g[1], g[2], g[3]);
    for (int i=0; i<cnt; i++)
        vec1 += vec2;
    return vec1.GetSum();
};
```

This is the resulting disassembly:

```
FN(float*, float*, int):                             # @FN(float*, float*, int)
    vmovddup xmm0, qword ptr [rdi + 8]       # xmm0 = mem[0,0]
    vaddps  xmm0, xmm0, xmmword ptr [rdi]
    vmovshdup xmm1, xmm0              # xmm1 = xmm0[1,1,3,3]
    vaddss  xmm0, xmm0, xmm1
    vcvtss2sd xmm0, xmm0, xmm0
    ret
```

So it is completely ignoring the intrinsics. If I uncomment that part that should be doing the same thing in C++, a really long code appears, so it apparently starts understanding it.

Am I missing something or is this a bug in LLVM?

Comment: Maybe the compiler sees that zero is passed as `cnt`, propagates constant and optimizes the loop away.

Comment: You are loading and storing 32 bytes although your struct is only 16 bytes. Maybe clang detects this as UB and ignores it.

Comment: @chtz ha! You are right! Silly me. Though I'd expect it to throw an error or something, not just ignore the entire code :o

Comment: @AlexGuteniev: It isn't, though; `cnt` is a function arg for `FN`.  (Unless it assumes 0 to make the UB unreachable in the `operator+=` implementation, which would read outside the local var objects it gets pointers to.  Even though that's done with `may_alias` `_mm256_loadu_ps`.  Or perhaps the alignment-required `_mm256_store_ps` is part of what it's seeing?  Nope, storeu doesn't help.)  https://godbolt.org/z/dj59xazrf shows the original with gcc/clang (using storeu), https://godbolt.org/z/MMsrhKG37 shows a `_mm_loadu_ps` version which clang compiles as expected.  (I omitted -ffast-math)

Comment: By design whenever possible LLVM ignores everything about the intrinsics except the semantic behaviour, then picks its own lowering to assembly. This has some surprising consequences like happily compiling PPC Altivec code into ARM NEON, or using accepting AVX2 intrinsics in code despite targeting an SSE4 machine.